# Whats c# version of this visual basic code to make sbox table?

Tags: c#, vb.net

this is the code in visual basic i got to make sbox table in rijndael encryption:

```
Private Sub BuildSbox()
    Me.Sbox = New Byte(,) {{99, 124, 119, 123, 242, 107, 111, 197, 48, 1, 103, 43, 254, 215, 171, 118}, {202, 130, 201, 125, 250, 89, 71, 240, 173, 212, 162, 175, 156, 164, 114, 192}, {183, 253, 147, 38, 54, 63, 247, 204, 52, 165, 229, 241, 113, 216, 49, 21}, {4, 199, 35, 195, 24, 150, 5, 154, 7, 18, 128, 226, 235, 39, 178, 117}, {9, 131, 44, 26, 27, 110, 90, 160, 82, 59, 214, 179, 41, 227, 47, 132}, {83, 209, 0, 237, 32, 252, 177, 91, 106, 203, 190, 57, 74, 76, 88, 207}, {208, 239, 170, 251, 67, 77, 51, 133, 69, 249, 2, 127, 80, 60, 159, 168}, {81, 163, 64, 143, 146, 157, 56, 245, 188, 182, 218, 33, 16, 255, 243, 210}, {205, 12, 19, 236, 95, 151, 68, 23, 196, 167, 126, 61, 100, 93, 25, 115}, {96, 129, 79, 220, 34, 42, 144, 136, 70, 238, 184, 20, 222, 94, 11, 219}, {224, 50, 58, 10, 73, 6, 36, 92, 194, 211, 172, 98, 145, 149, 228, 121}, {231, 200, 55, 109, 141, 213, 78, 169, 108, 86, 244, 234, 101, 122, 174, 8}, {186, 120, 37, 46, 28, 166, 180, 198, 232, 221, 116, 31, 75, 189, 139, 138}, {112, 62, 181, 102, 72, 3, 246, 14, 97, 53, 87, 185, 134, 193, 29, 158}, {225, 248, 152, 17, 105, 217, 142, 148, 155, 30, 135, 233, 206, 85, 40, 223}, {140, 161, 137, 13, 191, 230, 66, 104, 65, 153, 45, 15, 176, 84, 187, 22}}
End Sub
```

could you show me what's the c# version of this?

Comment: You've missed out a lot of detail here ... what is an `sbox` and where does C# come into it? You should *describe* your problem

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a code conversion tool

Comment: thanks and sorry, this my frst time. next ill be more detail. the answer from Jon solve my problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to replace Me with this, ( with ] and lowercase new. Array initialiser can stay as is

```
this.Sbox = new Byte[,]  {{0,1},{1,2}};
```